# Как сохранять токен в localstorage?

Tags: reactjs, localstorage, fetch

```
    handleChange(event) {
        const { target: { name, value, checked } } = event;
        const content = name === 'rememberMe' ? checked : value;
        this.setState({
          [name]: content
        });
      }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const {
          email,
          rememberMe,
          password,
        } = this.state;

        localStorage.setItem('rememberMe', rememberMe);
        localStorage.setItem('email', rememberMe ? email : '');
        localStorage.setItem('password', rememberMe ? password : '');

        fetch('/login', {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
          },
        })
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.status);

            if (!res.ok) {
              alert('failed');
              throw new Error(`Received 
${res.status}`);
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(`${error}`);
          });
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        const rememberMe = localStorage.getItem('rememberMe') === 'true';
        const email = rememberMe ? localStorage.getItem('email') : '';
        const password = rememberMe ? localStorage.getItem('password') : '';
        this.setState({ email, password, rememberMe });
      };
```

У меня есть запрос, который отправляет в localstorage login и password и сохраняет там в виде строк, подскажите пожалуйста, как переделать данный код, чтобы в localstorage сохранялся токен и, соответственно, подставлялись данные в форму. Кучу ресурсов перерыл, практически ничего полезного.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот [официальная документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage).

// Сохраняет данные в текущий local store

```
localStorage.setItem("username", "John");
```

John должен быть строкой.

// Извлекает ранее сохраненные данные

```
alert( "username = " + localStorage.getItem("username"));
```